# (char*)&obj alternatives

Tags: c++, c++11, file-handling

I see this being commonly used in file handling, (char*)&obj.
There are so many casting methods available since C++11,like static cast, cant we employ one over these ?

Comment: It is basically used to just stream data one byte at a time, it acts essentially like a `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Some argue that `reinterpret_cast` ought to be used in this kind of situation, others use the C-style cast.  (I'm in the `reinterpret_cast` camp.)  It comes down to a matter of style and your team's convention.  Use what works best for your team.  I prefer the more verbose style, because that way I can `grep` for it much easier.

Comment: "commonly used in file handling, (char*)&obj". Can you put an example here? The cast to `(char*)` can be omitted in a lot of cases. If a binary write needs `char*`, it's a design error in my opinion. These functions should take `void *`.

Comment: @geza FWIW, `std::basic_ifstream::read` uses `char *`.

Comment: Also read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) on how `()`, a.k.a. C-style cast works in C++.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: If that `read` is designed to read from a binary stream, then that's a design error, in my opinion.

Comment: @geza: Binary data on a disk is read as bytes, so expecting a `char*` to write those bytes to is not wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The & sign is there to take the address of obj.

Example:

```
#include <cstdio>

void printData(const char* p, int n) {
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("byte %2d : %d\n", i, (int)p[i]);
}

struct DataStruct {
  int x;
  int y;
};

int main() {
  DataStruct obj;
  obj.x = 5;
  obj.y = 257;
  char* dataPtr = (char*)&obj;
  printData(dataPtr, sizeof(DataStruct));
  return 0;
}
```

where the (char*)&obj maneouver is used to get a char* that can be passed to the printData function which just wants an array of chars to print.

In that example, the line

```
char* dataPtr = (char*)&obj;
```

could instead have been written using reinterpret_cast like this:

```
char* dataPtr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&obj);
```

which would do the same thing. An advantage of using reinterpret_cast instead of the cryptic (char*)&obj is that when you write reinterpret_cast it becomes more clearly visible that you are doing something kind of strange and possibly dangerous at that point in the code.